# How to make a loading bar in Unity after the scene is already loaded

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a labyrinth that is automatically generating itself by giving number of rows and number of columns as a user in the start menu. Once the user clicks start, the labyrinth starts generating. If the numbers are a bit higher (for example 250x250), it takes maybe around one minute to generate the maze and start playing.

For example 250*250 is 62500 which equals the cells that has to be created. I have a variable that returns the percentage created cells (for example if that value returns 90%, that means around 50000 cells already were created).

How can I run that function every frame and get the percentage created cells, so I can visualize it as a progress bar. Everything I found was with scene loading but my scene is already loaded. Here is the method of generating the maze:

```
    public IEnumerator CreateLabyrinth()
    {
        if (LabyrinthCreateAllCells())
        {
            BuildLabyrinth(); //after the creation of the cells, this script builds the labyrinth
        }

        yield return null;
    }
```

and I call it in another class like

```
        StartCoroutine(labyrinth.CreateLabyrinth());
```

Comment: This coroutine has only one yield call at the end, it did not enjoy any advantages brought by using coroutine, what is the purpose of creating it? You may read this first: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Comment: I just added the `yield return null` where the cells are building so for every built cell it should run the yield return but nothing really changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi yield return null only works inside of the coroutine, you are running the method BuildLabyrinth and then doing the yield, you need to made some loop with yield return on each cycle of the loop if you want to do a progress bar.

Example

```
private IEnumerator GenerateMazeCoroutine()
{
       
   for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
   {
       for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
       {
           //Yield return each cycle of the loop
           yield return null;

           BuildCell(x,y);
       }
   }

   // Maze generation completed
   Debug.Log("Maze generated!");

   // Perform any additional actions after maze generation
}
```

Comment: So the yield return would automatically update the progress bar? If not in this example where do you call the progress bar update method?

Comment: @repinSlun to update the progress bar you need to add your logic after the buildCell(x,y);